# How efficient is it to access DataRows in DataTable by index

Tags: vb.net, datatable, datarowcollection

I want to know what happens when I reference a DataRow in a .NET DataTable by index. i.e:

```
Dim myTable = get_me_a_big_table()
Dim myVal As Object = myTable.Rows(50000)(0)
```

When writing c++ I got moderately addicted to storing data in array-type containers to support random access for speed. It bugs me that I can't find an explanation of how a row is retrieved when requesting it by index.

I've seen 1 post where it mentions that the rows are laid out in a tree structure and therefore retrieving by index will perform some sort of branching search. This would be unlike the basic list functionality where every record prior to the index desired has to be iterated through to count them.

The MSDN has absolutely no comments in the documentation of DataTable or DataRowCollection about this (AFAIK). Can someone tell me what kind of search is used?

Comment: You could go figure it out for yourself by reading the [source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/DataTable.cs,8aab738ad2b51b53)

Comment: As Alex points out, the source code is available if you want to check it. I doubt that accessing a row by its index is inefficient.